# How to show WPF DocumentViewer with Landscape Orientation?

Tags: wpf, printing, landscape, fixeddocument

I'm creating a simple (one page of letter size) FixedDocument and showing it on a DocumentViewer for print preview purposes.

It is easy to put the content as landscape just applying a rotate transform.

But cannot find any property or way to show the page as Landscape in the DocumentViewer How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Letter size : 27.94 cm x 21.59 cm (11 inches by 8.5 inches)

The DocumentViewer shows exactly how the FixedPage are - by its width and its height.
So to get a landscaped version, simply swap the width and the height of the FixedPage .

```
<FixedPage x:Name="FP1" Width="27.94cm" Height="21.59cm" />
```